# How to setup an ionic app to connect to a local webserver?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm setting up an new ionic app for Android and I would like it to load from a normal localhost:8000 based webserver on Chrome. I know how to setup the webserver, but the part I don't know how to do is to have the app connect to the webserver. In other words how can I get an ionic app to connect to a localhost webserver?

I've tried creating a new ionic app, and a regular cordova app in 2 separate places.

```
ionic start game
```

To create the ionic app.
Then I created the cordova app:

```
cordova create microGame
```

Then I copied the ionic.config.json from game into microGame.

Then I used:

```
ionic link
```

To link it to microGame.

Then I did this:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Then put it on the device:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Then finally turned on the webserver:

```
Cordova run browser
```

I see this in the browser:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lru6euh5cakf0fl/cordova_ready.png?dl=1

"Apache Cordova device is ready".

And this on the phone:
"Ionic Blank, The world is your oyster. If you get lost the docs will be your guide"

I also just found a link here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run

Could this help?

Comment: I've had it working before last night. But I lost the files to that setup and forgot how I did it.

Comment: Okay now I have it looking for the server, but...

Comment: It says a protocall error.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? sorry it is very unclear from your post;/

Comment: I tried to make it clear the best I could.

Comment: I want to see this picture on the phone, without the ssl protocol error.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lru6euh5cakf0fl/cordova_ready.png

Comment: But I'm using ionic apache cordova version. I want to see what is in my browser on the phone. (@https://localhost:8000)/(192.168.*.*:8000)

Comment: Wait Nevermind it is WORKING! I used ionic cordova run --live-reload-url=http://168.192.#.#:8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use:

```
ionic cordova run --live-reload-url=http://168.192.#.#:port
```

Where: 168.192.#.# is your local ip address.
And: port is where you're running your thing on.